# Trying to save radio button selection when returning to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on the Javascript is Sexy quiz and I'm stuck on the following task:

"Add a “Back” button to allow the user to go back and change her answer. The user can go back up to the first question. For the questions that the user has answered already, be sure to show the radio button selected, so that the user is not forced to answer the questions again, which she has completed."

I inserted the back button fine, but I can't figure out how to keep the radio button selected. Could someone please help me figure out how to do this. Thanks!

[Here is my CodePen for reference](http://codepen.io/kwikimart/pen/VjQQNK?editors=1111)

```
var totalScore = 0
var questionNumber = 0

var allQuestions = [{
    question: "Who is the 12th president of the United States?",
    choices: ["John Tyler", "James K. Polk", "Millard Fillmore", "Zachary Taylor"],
    answer: "Zachary Taylor"
},
{
    question: "What was the first capital of The Replublic of Texas?",
    choices: ["Austin", "West Columbia", "Houston", "Harrisburg"],
    answer: "West Columbia"
},
{
    question: "What is the capital of Rhode Island",
    choices: ["Providence", "Warwick", "Newport", "Westerly"],
    answer: "Providence"
},
{
    question: "Who will be the 2016-2017 NBA Rookie of the Year?",
    choices: ["Ben Simmons", "Dario Saric", "Joel Embiid", "Brandon Ingram"],
    answer: "Joel Embiid"
}
]

var correct = function () {
    totalScore += 1;
    questionNumber += 1;
    $("#questionDiv").remove();
    $("#quizDiv").append("<h3 id='correct'>That's Correct!</h3>");
    $("#correct").append("<p>Your score is " + totalScore)
    $("#correct").append("<button id='nextButton'>Next Question</button>");
    $("#nextButton").click(function(){
        $("#correct").remove();
        if(questionNumber === 4) {  
            final();
        }
        else {
            question(questionNumber);
        }
    });
}

var incorrect = function () {
    questionNumber +=1;
    $('input:radio[name=questionChoices]:checked').attr("checked", "checked");
    $("#questionDiv").remove();
    $("#quizDiv").append("<h3 id='incorrect'>Sorry, that's incorrect!</h3>");
    $("#incorrect").append("<p>Your score is " + totalScore)
    $("#incorrect").append("<button id='nextButton'>Next Question</button>");
    $("#nextButton").click(function(){
        $("#incorrect").remove();
        if(questionNumber === 4) {  
            final();
        } else {
            question(questionNumber);
        }
    });
}

var back = function () {
  if (questionNumber > 0) {
    questionNumber -= 1;
    $("#questionDiv").remove();
    question(questionNumber);
  } else {
    alert("This is the first question!")
  }
}

var final = function() {
    if (totalScore >= 3) {
        $("#quizDiv").append("<h3>Congratulations! Your final score was " + totalScore + "</h3>")
    }
    else {
        $("#quizDiv").append("<h3>Sorry! Your final score was only " + totalScore + "</h3>")
    }
}

var question = function (i) {
    $("#quizDiv").append("<div id='questionDiv'></div>");
    $("#questionDiv").append("<h2>Question " + (i + 1) + "</h1>");
    $("#questionDiv").append("<h3>" + allQuestions[i].question + "</h3>");
    $("#questionDiv").append("<input type = 'radio' name='questionChoices' value ='" + allQuestions[i].choices[0] + "'>" + "</input>");
    $("#questionDiv").append("<label for = " + allQuestions[i].choices[0] + ">" + allQuestions[i].choices[0] + "&nbsp;" + "</label>")
    $("#questionDiv").append("<input type = 'radio' name='questionChoices' value = '" + allQuestions[i].choices[1] + "'>" + "</input>");
    $("#questionDiv").append("<label for = " + allQuestions[i].choices[1] + ">" + allQuestions[i].choices[1] + "&nbsp;" + "</label>")
    $("#questionDiv").append("<input type = 'radio' name='questionChoices' value = '" + allQuestions[i].choices[2] + "'>" + "</input>");
    $("#questionDiv").append("<label for = " + allQuestions[i].choices[2] + ">" + allQuestions[i].choices[2] + "&nbsp;" + "</label>")
    $("#questionDiv").append("<input type = 'radio' name='questionChoices' value = '" + allQuestions[i].choices[3] + "'>" + "</input>");
    $("#questionDiv").append("<label for = " + allQuestions[i].choices[3] + ">" + allQuestions[i].choices[3] + "&nbsp;" + "</label>" + "</br>")
    $("#questionDiv").append("<button id='backButton'>Back</button>" + "<button id='submitButton'>Submit</button>");
    $("#backButton").click(function() {
         back();
  })
    $("#submitButton").click(function() {
        if($('input:radio[name=questionChoices]:checked').val() === allQuestions[i].answer) {
            correct();
        }
   else if (!$('input:radio[name=questionChoices]').is(':checked') ) {
          alert("Please insert a value!")
        }
        else {
            incorrect();
        }
    }); //click event
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#startButton").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        question(questionNumber);
    })
});
```

Comment: Firstly, keeping the answers at the frontend level is not something that is advisable as one can simply look them up by inspecting element in the browser. Now comes your problem. Then there two cases. Whether you have different urls for different questions or its just that there is one url and only the questions and options are changing. So what exactly is your case?

Answer (score 0):

You could easily store some cookies or query strings in the url, and then have the new page look at these values when you navigate somewhere.

Alternatively you can store the values into a variable array or other collection by never leaving the page in the first place and just updating a containing `<div>` or `<form>` with the next page's/question's html/data.